# Could NOT find FFmpeg (missing: swresample) (found version “56.1.0”)

Tags: linux, debian, ffmpeg, kali-linux

I try to install obs (Open Broadcaster Software) in my Kali Linux 2.

I follow this [instruction](https://github.com/jp9000/obs-studio/wiki/Install-Instructions#manually-compiling-on-debian-based-distros). I have no problem until the obs building:

```
cmake -DUNIX_STRUCTURE=1 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr ..
```

Where I get this error:

```
Could NOT find FFmpeg (missing: swresample) (found version "56.1.0")
```

I found this [topic](https://debian-facile.org/viewtopic.php?id=13606) but I can't use this command:

```
apt-get -t jessie-backports install libswresample-dev
```

Because I am on Kali Linux.

This is the output of `ffmpeg` command:

```
ffmpeg version N-79093-g7916f04 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10)
  configuration: --prefix=/root/ffmpeg_build --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags=-I/root/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/root/bin --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      55. 19.100 / 55. 19.100
  libavcodec     57. 28.103 / 57. 28.103
  libavformat    57. 28.102 / 57. 28.102
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 39.102 /  6. 39.102
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...

Use -h to get full help or, even better, run 'man ffmpeg'
```

Answer (score 2):

To install some package from [Backports](https://backports.debian.org/) you nedd to edit your `sources.list`:

```
echo 'deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie-backports main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list
```

Then install the needed package:

```
apt-get update
apt-get -t jessie-backports install libswresample-dev
```

**NB**

> Backports cannot be tested as extensively as Debian stable, and backports are provided on an as-is basis, with risk of incompatibilities with other components in Debian stable. Use with care!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't want break my Kali so I will install Debian on a other laptop.